# Finding 'xyz' in a string but not '.xyz'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to write a boolean that is true if 'xyz' is in a string, but is not preceded by a '.'

My problem is I can get most use cases to work but not if there is a '.xyz' with match but nothing else, which I think should be covered in the False side of the boolean.

My code is:

```
def xyz_there(s):
  return (('xyz' in s and '.xyz' not in s) or ('xyz' in s and '.xyz' in s))
```

use cases: (call - the expected result -- the result I'm getting)

```
xyz_there('abcxyz') → True  True
xyz_there('abc.xyz') → False    True    
xyz_there('xyz.abc') → True True    
xyz_there('abcxy') → False  False   
xyz_there('xyz') → True True    
xyz_there('xy') → False False   
xyz_there('x') → False  False       
xyz_there('') → False   False   
xyz_there('abc.xyzxyz') → True  True
xyz_there('abc.xxyz') → True    True    
xyz_there('.xyz') → False   True    
xyz_there('12.xyz') → False True        
xyz_there('12xyz') → True   True    
xyz_there('1.xyz.xyz2.xyz') → False True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you like simple elegant code ?

```
def xyz_there(s): 
    return s.count('xyz') > s.count('.xyz')
```

To check the solution, execute your tests this way

```
def tests():
    assert xyz_there('abcxyz') is True # → True  True
    assert xyz_there('abc.xyz') is False # → False    True    
    assert xyz_there('xyz.abc') is True # → True True    
    assert xyz_there('abcxy') is False # → False  False   
    assert xyz_there('xyz') is True # → True True    
    assert xyz_there('xy') is False # → False False   
    assert xyz_there('x') is False # → False  False       
    assert xyz_there('') is False # → False   False   
    assert xyz_there('abc.xyzxyz') is True # → True  True
    assert xyz_there('abc.xxyz') is True # → True    True    
    assert xyz_there('.xyz') is False # → False   True    
    assert xyz_there('12.xyz') is False # → False True        
    assert xyz_there('12xyz') is True # → True   True    
    assert xyz_there('1.xyz.xyz2.xyz') is False # → False True
```

Then call `tests()`

**Basic explanation:**

Keep in mind that any time the string '.xyz' occurs, the string 'xyz' is also occuring at the same time because 'xyz' is included inside '.xyz'. So for it to have an extra 'xyz' that is not preceded by a '.' you would have to have more of 'xyz' substrings than '.xyz' substrings.

Comment: This works great. I just have to try and understand how it all works. Thank you.

Comment: I have added a basic explanation that might help you @JustinReynolds

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a failing test.

`xyz_there('abc.xyz')`

This should get False and is getting True.

We can plug in the results of evaluating your expression and see how the logic works out.

`(('xyz' in s and '.xyz' not in s) or ('xyz' in s and '.xyz' in s))`

`((True and False) or (True and True))`

`((False) or (True))`

`((True))`

The expression on the right side of the `or` will always be true when the string contains '.xyz', so in that case, the expression will always be True, but that is the string that is not supposed to qualify for a True return value.

Looking only at whether 'xyz' and '.xyz' occur in the string is on the wrong track, anyway.  If there are multiple occurrences of 'xyz' in the string, you have check each one individually to see if it is preceded by a '.', and you have to look at the results of all of those checks to see if there is an 'xyz' that is not preceded by a '.'.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. I can see and somewhat understand what you are saying. I'm just not sure where to start with it. I'm guessing a for loop to see if the string contains 'xyz' and if so then if it's proceeded by a '.'??

Comment: I see while I have been pondering your comment, others have added three more solutions, so I don't know if you need any more help from me.  There are lots of ways to do it.  For example, in addition to those posted, you could use the `find` function in a `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. I'll give that a shot too. While, yes, my question has been answered. I'd also like to look at solving it in different ways to broaden my knowledge, so I very much appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This might be easiest with a regex to look for `xyz` using a negative lookbehind for a `.`:

```
import re

def xyz_there(s):
    return re.search(r'(?<!\.)xyz', s) is not None
```

If you can't use regex, you could compare every 4 character substring of `s` with `*xyz` where `*` can be any character other than `.`:

```
def xyz_there(s):
    return s.startswith('xyz') or any(s[i] != '.' and s[i+1:i+4] == 'xyz' for i in range(0, len(s)-2))
```

The `any` loop can be unrolled into a simple `for` loop:

```
def xyz_there(s):
    if s.startswith('xyz'):
        return True
    for i in range(0, len(s)-2):
        if s[i] != '.' and s[i+1:i+4] == 'xyz':
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes that would definitely work, however, it's asking me to us any imports. Can I use regex without importing re?

Comment: @JustinReynolds no, you do have to import re to use regex. Do you need to solve the problem without any?

Comment: @JustinReynolds I've added a solution that doesn't require the use of any imports

Comment: I appreciate it. I'm sure that seems pretty basic, but that code, at least written that way is just a bit over my head. I do thank you for trying to help me understand.

Comment: @JustinReynolds I've added another solution which is the same code as the second, but with the `any` unrolled into a `for` loop

Comment: lol thank you. THAT i understand. :). Sometimes trying to learn this stuff is humbling. It's so hard not to get frustrated and feel stupid. I guess persistence and practice are the ticket. :)

Comment: @JustinReynolds we've **all** been there. Persistence and practice are indeed the ticket.

Answer (score -1):

This is my code. Not the most elegant but it works.

```
    def xyz_there(str):
    x = str.replace (".xyz", "A")
      if "xyz" in x:
        return True
      else:
       return False
```